# Spring Boot with Thymeleaf 3 using OGNL or SpEL or a mix?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot 1.4 with Thymeleaf 3. 
What syntax is used? OGNL or SpEL?
Appendix A lists no Thymeleaf parameter to configure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the *spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf* it configures automatically the integration of Thymeleaf with Spring, using the *SpringTemplateEngine* and the [*SpringStandardDialect*](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#the-springstandard-dialect).

That means the active variable expression language is SpEL. It also provides other [integration features](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#the-springstandard-dialect). The links point to the 2.1 version documentation, but I think it's the same in the 3.0 version.

Comment: The link to the Thymeleaf 3.0 documentation about the SpringStandardDialect is: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#the-springstandard-dialect